# adding animation to change text intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have created the following script to change the text on a span:

```
var texts = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    var count = 0;
    function changeText() {
        $("#example").text(texts[count]);
        count < 5 ? count++ : count = 0;
    }
    setInterval(changeText, 900);

number: <br /><span style="color:orange" id="example">1</span>
```

Is there a way to add animations when the text changes??

Comment: maybe you should Google that first

Answer (score 0):

I have just added one way in which you can add animations. 
Using hide and show methods of Jquery with 800 milliseconds as speed of effect

```js
var texts = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    var count = 0;
    function changeText() {
        $("#example").hide()
       .text(texts[count])
       .show(800);
        
        count < 5 ? count++ : count = 0;
    }
    setInterval(changeText, 900);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
number: <br /><span style="color:orange" id="example">1</span>
```